# UIImageView is not scrolling inside a scrollView

Tags: objective-c, swift, iphone, xcode, scrollview

I am creating a scrollview with a page control. I have a scrollview added to my viewcontroller and inside the scrollview there is a UIImageView. But for some reason I cannot scroll it to the left or right side. Can anyone help me out to fix this problem?

My Code:

```
    var tutorialImages: [String] = ["1", "2", "3"]
var frame = CGRect.zero

func pageControll() {
    pageControllTutorial.numberOfPages = tutorialImages.count

    for i in 0..<tutorialImages.count {


        imageViewTutorial.frame = frame
        imageViewTutorial.image = UIImage(named: tutorialImages[i])
        scrollViewTutorial.addSubview(imageViewTutorial)
    }

    scrollViewTutorial.contentSize = CGSize(width: imageViewTutorial.frame.size.width * CGFloat(tutorialImages.count), height: imageViewTutorial.frame.size.height)

    scrollViewTutorial.delegate = self
}


func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    var pageNumber = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width
    pageControllTutorial.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use explicit frames instead of auto-layout?

Comment: I was following a tutorial on YouTube and it worked, but not as expected. With auto layout it didn't work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the little bit of code you've shown, you're doing a number of things wrong.

Based on this line:

```
imageViewTutorial.image = UIImage(named: tutorialImages[I])
```

it *looks* like you have one `UIImageView` and you are setting its `.image` property 3 times, instead of creating 3 different image views.

Also, there is nothing in your code indicating how you are setting the frames of the image views.

I highly recommend using auto-layout instead of explicit frames - makes things much, much easier going forward.

Here is a complete example. It will create a square (1:1 ratio) scroll view 20-pts from the top with 20-pts padding on each side, and a `UIPageControl` below. It then adds a horizontal `UIStackView` to the scroll view. That stack view will hold the image views. Once the image views are added, the stack view will automatically define the "scrollable area" -- no need for calculating `.contentSize`.

Here's what it will look like:

[image]

Everything is done in code, so just assign the class of an empty view controller to `SlidesExampleViewController` ... no `@IBOutlet` or `@IBAction` connections needed.

```
class SlidesExampleViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    lazy var pageControl: UIPageControl = {
        let v = UIPageControl()
        v.backgroundColor = .brown
        return v
    }()

    lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let v = UIScrollView(frame: .zero)
        v.backgroundColor = .yellow
        v.delegate = self
        return v
    }()

    lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.axis = .horizontal
        v.alignment = .fill
        v.distribution = .fill
        v.spacing = 0
        return v
    }()

    let tutorialImages: [String] = ["1", "2", "3"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .white

        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        pageControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        view.addSubview(pageControl)
        scrollView.addSubview(stackView)

        let v = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        let g = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // constrain scroll view to top, leading, trailing with 20-pts "padding"
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),

            // constrain scroll view height equal to scroll view width
            scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor),

            // constrain stack view to all 4 sides of scroll view's contentLayoutGuide
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),

            // constrain stack view height equal to scroll view height
            stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.heightAnchor),

            // constrain page control width to 80% of scroll view width
            pageControl.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.8),

            // constrain page control top to 8-pts below scroll view bottom
            pageControl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),

            // constrain page control centerX to centerX of scroll view
            pageControl.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor, constant: 0.0),

        ])

        tutorialImages.forEach { name in
            if let img = UIImage(named: name) {
                let imgView = UIImageView(image: img)
                stackView.addArrangedSubview(imgView)
                imgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
            }
        }

        pageControl.numberOfPages = tutorialImages.count

        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true

    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let pageIndex = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x/view.frame.width)
        pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageIndex)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Increase the contentSize of scroll view As (number of images * width of image) expecting all image are equal in size.

int startPosition = 0;
set the image origin.x

1 image1.frame.origin.x = startPosition;
   startPosition =  startPosition + image1.frame.size.width;

2 image2.frame.origin.x = startPosition;
  startPosition =  startPosition + image2.frame.size.width;

3 image3.frame.origin.x = startPosition;
  startPosition =  startPosition + image3.frame.size.width;

or either you can put these in a for loop to set the frame size of image.

Answer (score 0):

The `frame` of each UIImageView is being set to CGRect.zero so they all have a 0 height and width, which means your scroll views contentSize is also 0x0. As far as the scroll view is concerned, there's nothing *to* scroll here.

Do this instead:

```
let image = UIImage(named: tutorialImages[i])
imageViewTutorial.frame = CGRect(x: widthSoFar, y: 0, width: image.width, height: image.height)
imageViewTutorial.image = image
scrollViewTutorial.addSubview(imageViewTutorial)
widthSoFar += image.size.width
```

Initialize `widthSoFar` *outside* the for loop to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Always Keep the

1. Scroll view size is greater or equal to Imageview size.
2. check and keep UIImageView userInteraction Enable.
3. keep scroll view Content size as big as your number of image like for four
   image in scoll view then (imageview.frame.size.width*4)

Content size = CGSize(imageview.frame.size.width*4,imageview.frame.size.height).